# How do I rollback transaction in django-rest-framework APIView?

Tags: django, transactions, django-rest-framework

From below view. I try to force transaction to rollback. But no work. The data still inserted to database. Can someone give me the right way?

```
class DocumentDetailView(APIView):
        def post(self, request):
            sid = transaction.savepoint()
            serializer = DocumentSerializer(Documents(), data=request.data)
            if serializer.is_valid():
                serializer.save()
                transaction.savepoint_rollback(sid)
                return HttpResponse(JSONRenderer().render(serializer.data), status=201)
            else:
                return HttpResponse(JSONRenderer().render(serializer.errors), status=400)
```

Answer (score 4):

try using transaction.atomic()

```
with transaction.atomic():
    serializer.save()
    transaction.set_rollback(True)
```